# I can't select the second option based on the first drop down option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mern

So I figure it out how can I render a specific `productCategory` depending on the `category` or the first dropdown.

[image]

But, when I try to pick `productCategory`, nothing happens.

I'm looping the information of the category from my dataTabels.jsx.

AddProduct.js

```
 const [itemName, setItemName] = useState({
    category: '',
    productCategory: '',
  })

  const CAHScategory = [
    'CAHS Merchandise',
    'CAHS Related Softwares',
    'Clinical Equipments',
    'Others',
  ]
  const CASEcategory = [
    'CASE Merchandise',
    'CASE Related Softwares',
    'Laboratory Equipments',
    'Others',
  ]

   let Itemtype = null
   let OptionType = null
   if(itemName.category === 'CAHS'){
    Itemtype = CAHScategory
   }
   else if(itemName.category === 'CASE'){
    Itemtype = CASEcategory

   }


  return (
     <FormControl fullWidth>  
              <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Category</InputLabel>
            <Select
              fullWidth
              labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
              id="demo-simple-select"
              name="categories"
              defaultValue=""
              label="categories"
              onChange={(e) => setItemName({...itemName, category: e.target.value})}
              required
            >
                {itemTables.map((item) =>(
                  <MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.cat}>
                      {item.name}
                  </MenuItem>              
              ))}
                
            </Select>
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl fullWidth>  
              <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Product Category</InputLabel>
            <Select
              fullWidth
              labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
              id="demo-simple-select"
              name="productCategory"
              defaultValue=""
              label="productCategory"
              onChange={(e) => setItemName({...itemName, productCategory: e.target.value})}
              required
            >         
               {Itemtype ? (
                Itemtype.map((el) => <MenuItem key={el}>{el}</MenuItem>)
               ): null}
            </Select>
       </FormControl>
  )
```

dataTables.jsx

```
export const itemTables =[
    {
        id: '1',
        name: "College of Allied Health and Sciences",
        cat: 'CAHS',
        to: '/category/CAHS',
        img: 'https://i.ibb.co/D98jG7d/312498729-1132402804318856-1848067548745320262-n.jpg',
      
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        name: "College of Arts, Sciences and Education",
        cat: 'CASE',
        to: '/category/CASE',
        img: 'https://i.ibb.co/LSsHw2T/102719225-104074154675775-86515862277755112-n.jpg',

    },
]
```

[codebox of the actual problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-pine-cl3r2c?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to include the value.

```
 {Itemtype ? (
    Itemtype.map((el) => <MenuItem value={el} key={el}>{el}</MenuItem>)
  ): null}
```